# I want to check if there is a 'int+specific word' in a string

Tags: python, python-3.x

there! Well, usually I ask questions about strings with English examples, but in the last time, I found that there can be some problems because of the difference in grammar(like... when using split()). So I'll ask the question with Korean examples.

So what I want to know is like this. I want to know if the string has `int+'일' like, 3일 5일 6일 9일 11일 20일 (which means the date btw, so int should be 1~31)`
But I have no idea how to check the word of    `int+'일'   .`
As you already noticed, int should be placed right before the word `'일'`

```
ex_A = '오늘은 3월 3일 입니다.'
ex_B = '오늘은 4월의 어느날이야.'
ex_C = '내일은 3월인데 삼일절이 있는 날이야.'
```

`ex_A should return True` while `ex_B` and `ex_C` will `return False`. `ex_B doesn't have '일'` in it, and `ex_C has both int and '일'` in it, but that int is not placed right before the word '일'.

So... it must be a basic question, will there be a way for it? I was thinking about making a characters right before '일' into int and see if there's an error for it.

But I think you will have more fantastic ideas :) Thanks!

Comment: SO is no code writing service. Where is your try at it and what went wrong with it? Can you elaborate on how your code "doesn't work"? What were you expecting, and what actually happened? If you got an exception/error, post the line it occurred on and the exception/error details as per the How to Create a [mcve] page. Please [edit] your question to add these details into it or we may not be able to help.

Comment: @PatrickArtner Ah, sorry Patrick. I was trying to learn more efficient way. I'll make sure to write down my limit for the next times.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Probably the best way is to use [regular expressions](https://docs.python.org/3/library/re.html):

```
import re

ex_A = '오늘은 3월 3일 입니다.'
ex_B = '오늘은 4월의 어느날이야.'
ex_C = '내일은 3월인데 삼일절이 있는 날이야.'

pattern = "\d{1,2}일"

sA = re.findall(pattern, ex_A)
sB = re.findall(pattern, ex_B)
sC = re.findall(pattern, ex_C)
print(sA)
print(sB)
print(sC)
```

Output:

```
['3일']
[]
[]
```

`pattern` is the regular expression which is used for the search:

- `\d` means any digit from 0 to 9.
- `{1,2}` means one or two occurencies
- `일` means 일

So using `\d{1,2}일` as a search pattern you search for a sequence of one or two digits followed by 일.

***Update:**

Since you only need numbers from 1 to 31 you can use pattern `"([0-9]|[12][0-9]|3[01])일"`

However the output on your data is then

```
['3']
[]
[]
```

so, without 일 and I cannot expain why.

Comment: Yeah! Just what I wanted xD and thanks for the kind explanations as well. I was curious about how to deal with occurencies as well. :D

Comment: Checked! But since it can catch if there is a pattern goes in the string, I think I can handle the rest :D Really interesting about setting patterns. I should study harder.
Thanks for update!

Answer (score 2):

`re.search` ought work:

```py
pattern = re.compile(r'\d+일')
strings = [
    '오늘은 3월 3일 입니다.',
    '오늘은 4월의 어느날이야.',
    '내일은 3월인데 삼일절이 있는 날이야.',
]
print([pattern.search(s) for s in strings])
```

will print `[<_sre.SRE_Match object; span=(7, 9), match='3일'>, None, None]` (so essentially true, false, false).

You will probably want to make the numeric pattern more precise than `\d+` (which is any sequence of numbers so e.g. `99일` will match).

Answer (score 2):

use regex,

```
>>> ex_A = '오늘은 3월 3일 입니다.'
>>> ex_A
'\xec\x98\xa4\xeb\x8a\x98\xec\x9d\x80 3\xec\x9b\x94 3\xec\x9d\xbc \xec\x9e\x85\xeb\x8b\x88\xeb\x8b\xa4.'
>>> import re
>>> g = re.search('\d일', ex_A)
>>> g.group()
'3\xec\x9d\xbc'
```

**\d - match your integer
일 - matches your string**